# Matlab Simulink scope log or saved data

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink model with a scope output that I want to observe. However, I want the data shown on the previous simulation while being stopped to be continuously shown on the scope window, or saved to a file somewhere. Is there any easy way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question.  Do you want the data from a previous simulation, or while the model is paused?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about showing it on the scope, but you can save the data shown in a scope to a workspace variable, and then save that variable to a mat file.

See the section on **Save data to workspace** in the [scope documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/scope.html)

Comment: Thanks, found out momentarily before your response.